# 500 Responsecode while using warbler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, warbler

I've tried to deploy a simple RubyOnRails app to tomcat app-server with the warbler gem. I simply generated a new app, with a simple scaffold and configured it to use the jdbcmysql adapter. Then i simply created and migrated the database, executed warbler and deployed the war to my local tomcat (Version 6.0.23). I can deploy the war and if i hit the app it shows the RubyOnRails 'Welcome' page. But if i hit a controller, the app response with a 500 Error code. The logs (catalina.out ...) stay empty.

I use the current gem versions of rails, warbler and jdbcmysql, the stable release of tomcat and the jruby package in ubuntu (testing).

Are there any suggestions? Where can i find additional information, logs.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There where two issues to work around:

1. The jruby-rack.jar is broken. A workaround is described here:

kenai.com/jira/browse/JRUBY_RACK-18

Or follow the instructions on:

stufftohelpyouout.blogspot.com/2009/06/how-to-get-warbler-to-include-custom.html

with the jruby-rack snapshot from:

http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/org/jruby/rack/jruby-rack/0.9.5-SNAPSHOT/

2. There is a fix needed to use warbler with RubyOnRails 2.3.2. Have a look at:

kenai.com/projects/jruby/pages/Rails_2_3_2